# Trying to move an array to a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to move goals from an array to a tableview and am having trouble accomplishing this task.

Here is my code.

```
import UIKit

class GoalsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var goalTableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var goalCategoryLabel: UILabel!

var valueToPass = ""
var goals: [String] = []
let theEmptyModel: [String] = ["No data in this section."]

var firstGoals = ["run", "walk", "jog"]
var secondGoals = ["sleep", "rest"]

var goalCategoryText: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    goals = firstGoals
    goalCategoryLabel?.text = goalCategoryText
    goalTableView.delegate = self
    goalTableView.dataSource = self
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "firstGoalsSegue" {
        if goalCategoryText == "First Goals" {
            let viewController = segue.destination as! GoalsViewController
            viewController.firstGoals.append(valueToPass)
        }
    }
    if segue.identifier == "secondGoalsSegue" {
        if goalCategoryText == "Second Goals" {
            let viewController = segue.destination as! GoalsViewController
            viewController.secondGoals.append(valueToPass)
        }
    }

}

extension GoalsViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return goals.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GoalsCell_1", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = goals[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "\(sectionHeader)"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    valueToPass = goals[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "firstGoalsSegue", sender: self)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondGoalsSegue", sender: self)
    tableview.reloadData()
}
}
```

Here is my storyboard. 
[image: Storyboard]

Currently, when selecting a button, I am brought to a tableview screen that only displays empty cells. How would I fix my code so that the values of firstGoals and secondGoals are passed to the tableview when the respected button is tapped?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `GoalTableView`'s `delegate` and `dataSource` to the `GoalsViewController`, like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    goals = ["goal 1", "goal 2", "goal 3"]
    goalCategoryLabel?.text = goalCategoryText
    GoalTableView.delegate = self
    GoalTableView.dataSource = self
    GoalTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Tip: Try to maintain names that start with small letter for instances, in this case rename `GoalTableView` to `goalTableView`.

Comment: Thanks. When I implement this, I still get a blank tableView.

Comment: You might also need to set the `goals` array. I've updated my answer check once again.

Comment: Thanks. Using this it displays goals in the tableView, but it will only display firstGoals in each tableView. How do I get it so that firstGoals is shown in its proper tableView as well as secondGoals?